# Algorithm for solving the maximum boolean satisfiability prob in python

Tags: python, recursion, boolean

I'm having some trouble making an algorithm for solving the maximum boolean satisfiability problem in python. I'm supposed to implement a solve function that takes a parameter f (python function corresponding to a formula) which returns a list of values that satisfies f and has the largest possible number of True values. 
I was given the following helper function:

```
def count(values):
    return len([v for v in values if v == True])
```

which can be used in this way:

```
count([True, False, True, False])
    2
```

This is the exact problem given:

**Implement a recursive function solve(f) that takes as its first argument a single function f (i.e., a Python function corresponding to a formula). The function f may take any non-zero quantity of arguments. The function solve(f) should return a list of values that satisfies f and has the largest possible number of True values (as many as any other list of values that satisfies f).**

Here's what I have so far:

```
def solve(f, values = []):
    if (len(values) == len(variables(f))):
        if(f(*values) == True):
            return values
```

Which is basically the base case. But now I'm completely stuck.

If someone could complete this for me, and explain what they did I'd be forever grateful!

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT 1:**
Here's the function variables(f)

```
def variables(f):
    return list(f.__code__.co_varnames)
```

Comment: a small aside: `[True, False, True, False].count(True)` returns 2 as well, built in :)

Comment: What is `variables(f)`? Does f always return a boolean? I don't get the question.

Comment: What are domain and codomain of the function f? If the domain is infinite, the number of solutions may be infinite too. When is f "satisfied"?

Comment: Another side note: you can also substitute `count` with `sum`... Always know your tools ;)

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, but because of my knowledge level of Python I'm still just as stuck lol. I added the function variables(f), sorry about forgetting it.

Comment: The main idea is that if you have less variables set than needed, return the maximum (wrt. the number of True values) of the result of solve(current variabls plus True) and solve(current variables plus False).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is optimal by any means, but here's a simple recursive solution that tests all possible inputs:

```
def solve(f, values=[]):
    if len(variables(f)) == len(values):
        if f(*values):
            return values
        else:
            return None

    true_results = solve(f, values+[True])
    false_results = solve(f, values+[False])
    if false_result is None:
        return true_result
    if true_result is None or count(false_result) > count(true_result):
        return false_result
    return true_result
```